# ajp/1.3 port no is not showing in apache tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was running my web program in eclipse ide using apache tomcat but while changing my port number I didn't find ajp/1.3 port, I think in past while solving an error I tried to change it and now it's not there, I tried to reinstall apache tomcat but still, it's not coming.

[image: this is an image of tomcat server]
[image]
 please help me

Comment: Make sure that the tomcat server.xml file contains AJP protocol.

Comment: @Pandurang please explain how to do that I'm a beginner, I've put a screenshot of server.xml in my question

Comment: A screenshot of text? Please replace by actual text

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tomcat server conf($Tomcat_Home/conf) directory and check the AJP connector available or not in server.xml. If not the add below entry in server.xml after HTTP connector.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: please check I've updated it in my question in the second image could you check it, if it is right or not

Comment: Looks like AJP connector is commented.could you please uncomment AJP connector and test.